# Enclosing multiple fhir resource in a single resource

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I am currently working to standardize communication between a lab and clinic server. I am working on a basic workflow that returns a **DiagnosticReport** type FHIR resource from the clinic server. According to FHIR only references of **Observations** are passed as part of the **DiagnosticReport** and a new hit to the clinic server is to be made to fetch every actual **Observation** type FHIR resource. The question is that is there a way to make the **Observation** resources part of the **DiagnosticReport** resource and save the extra hits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, by using contained resources. But there's a much better option - use the _include option to retrieve all the observations with the DiagnosticReport in the first place

Answer (score 3):

Contained resources aren't intended as a packaging mechanism, but rather to hold information that can't stand alone.  Containment means that the data isn't independently accessible.  So _include is a much better approach.